# Value of post does not update

Tags: php, database, post, phpmyadmin

I have created a reservation form. The user has the option when selecting a residence option from the drop down menu to not choose one, so the value would be 'Select One...'. If they do not select a residence area, once they submit the form it brings them to another page which gives them a drop down list of the options they have for residence areas based on their class and preferences. The results from the form print out on the third page with their name, gender, residence area, etc. The problem is that I retrieve the residence area by using $_POST["dorm"]. This works when the user does select a residence area, but if they do not, then the $_POST doesn't seem to update and reads as 'Select One...'.

Here is my code for the page that gives the user their residence area options:

```
<html>
<?php
require 'sql_helper.php';
echo " <form action = \"results2.php\" method = \"post\">\n<br> ";

//Read the information entered on the index page
$specialNeeds = isset($_POST["specialNeeds"]);
$laundry = isset($_POST["laundry"]);
$fullyEquippedKitchen = isset($_POST["fullyEquippedKitchen"]);
$class = $_POST["class"];
$dorm = $_POST["dorm"];

//If user did not choose a dorm
if ($dorm == "Select One...") { 
    $sql = "SELECT name, roomsAvailable FROM $dormTable WHERE class = $class || class = 'Select One...'"; 
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo " <strong>Residence Areas</strong>\n ";
        echo " <select name = dorm> \n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++){
            $aDorm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $dormName = $aDorm['name'];
            $dormAvailable = $aDorm['roomsAvailable'];
        if($dormName != 'Select One...'){
            echo "<option value = \"$dormName\" > $dormName ($dormAvailable)</option>\n";
        }
        elseif ($dormAvailable == 0 && $dormName != 'Select One...'){
            echo "<option value = \"$dormName\" disabled=\"disabled\"> $dormName </option> \n";
        }

        elseif ($dormName == 'Select One...'){
            echo "<option value = \"$dormName\" disabled=\"disabled\" selected = \"true\"> $dormName </option> \n";
        }
            }
            echo "</select>\n<br><br>";
    } 
   foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
       echo"<input type = hidden name = $k value = \"$v\" ><?php echo print_r($_POST) ?>";
   }

   echo " <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\"> \n <br> ";
} 
//If user did choose a dorm
else { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $dormTable WHERE name = '$dorm'";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $dormRecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        if ($class == $dormRecord['class']) {
            unset($errorString);

            // check preferences
            if ($fullyEquippedKitchen) {
                if (!$dormRecord['fullyEquippedKitchen']) {
                    $errorString = "$dormRecord[name] does not have a kitchen.\n";
                     echo $errorString;
                     echo 'Go back to the previous page to re-enter your preferences.<br><br>';
                     echo '<a href = "index2.php">Go back</a><br><br>';
                }
                else{
                    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
                        echo"<input type = hidden name = $k value = \"$v\"> <?php echo print_r($_POST) ?>";
                     }
                    echo "Your preferences are a match!<br>";
                    echo " <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\"> \n <br> ";
                }
            }
            else{
                foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
                    echo"<input type = hidden name = $k value = \"$v\"> <?php echo print_r($_POST) ?>";
                }
                echo "Your preferences are a match!<br>";
                echo " <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\"> \n <br> ";
            }
        } 
        else {
            $errorString = "You cannot live in $dormRecord[name] because of your class status.\n";
            echo $errorString;
            echo 'Go back to the previous page to re-enter your preferences.<br><br>';
            echo '<a href = "index2.php">Go back</a><br><br>';
        }

    } 
    else {
        echo "something is wrong: ".mysqli_error($conn);
        die;
    }
    ?>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you try using `OR` instead of `||` in the query? Also `<select name = dorm>` missing quotes around `dorm` and on some more inputs below.

Comment: yes, you are right about that part, thank you, but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: I am not sure how lines like this even work: `echo"<input type = hidden name = $k value = \"$v\"> <?php echo print_r($_POST) ?>";`. Should give syntax error I would think. At the very least wouldn't print the array as expected.